# Trying to add a feature to my (basic) level parsing algorithm - not sure how to (JAVA)

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx, 2d

Right now this method goes through a list of `GameObjects` (e.g. `JetPack`, `Platform`) with their respective x and y positions in a text file called level1.txt:

```
platform 840 280
platform 1130 280
coin 900 300
coin 950 300
coin 1000 300
coin 1000 400
jetpack 1090 400
platform 650 500
platform 500 400
platform 200 400
NEXT
platform 200 200
coin 250 300
coin 350 700
```

What currently happens is whenever my Player reaches the end of the screen, he goes back to the start (x = 0). When he does reach the end of the screen, I want all the objects BEFORE `NEXT`to disappear and all the objects AFTER `NEXT` to be drawn. I know why my algorithm doesn't work as it should but I'm unsure how to fix it. Can anyone have a look at it and tell me how I can modify it to do what I want it to? `list`is a list of GameObjects in the text file btw.

```
public void loadLevel(String level) {
        list.clear();
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal(level);
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(file.readString());
        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String type = tokens.nextToken();

            if (type.equals("platform")) {
                list.add(new Platform(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()),
                        Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())));
            }
            else if (type.equals("coin")) {
                list.add(new Coin(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()), Integer
                        .parseInt(tokens.nextToken())));
            } else if (type.equals("flag")) {
                list.add(new Flag(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()), Integer
                        .parseInt(tokens.nextToken())));
            } else if (type.equals("jetpack")) {
                list.add(new JetPack(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()),
                        Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())));
            } else if (type.equals("pipe")) {
                list.add(new Pipe(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()), Integer
                        .parseInt(tokens.nextToken())));
            } else if (type.equals("NEXT") && player.getxPos() > SCREEN_WIDTH) {
                list.clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the List into a HashMap

```
HashMap<Integer, List<GameObject>> levels = new HashMap<>();
```

Add a new variable:

```
int levelIndex = 0;

// Initialize first list.
levels.put(levelIndex, new ArrayList<GameObject>());
```

run through the file, putting everything into the

```
levels.get(levelIndex).add(object);
```

When you reach Next

```
levelIndex++;
levels.put(levelIndex, new ArrayList<GameObject>());
```

When player reaches the edge of the screen - update which level you draw from using a similar index

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I'm not quite sure how to update the level when the player reaches the end of the screen since I'm pretty unfamiliar with HashMaps. Would it involve looping over the HashMap by adding 1 to the index every time the Player reaches the end? I'm not on my PC atm

Comment: when drawing, instead of drawing from your current list like this: `for(Object obj : list){
// Do stuff
}`

Then do this:
`for(Object obj : levels.get(levelIndex)){
// Do stuff
}`


At start of the game, after loading the levels from the file
`int levelIndex = 0`
When player reaches the edge of the screen - `levelIndex++`

Comment: Cheers. I'll give this a go and get back to you.